# GWT Disable horizontal drag scrolling

Tags: jquery, gwt, drag-and-drop, gquery

I have a celltable inside a scroll panel. That way I can vertically scroll through all the items. I have been using the gquery plugin for drag and drop functionality. I am wanting to drag an item from one table to another. My problem is that when I try to drag and item from table 1 to table 2, the scroll panel is doing a horizontal autoscroll, so my item is never escaping the scroll panel. How do I drag and item outside the scroll panel?

Answer (score 0):

You will get horizontal overflow if and only if the widget within the scroll panel (i.e. the one you set using `flowPanel.setWidget(widget)`) is horizontally larger than the scroll panel.

The easiest way to avoid this is to use a standard FlowPanel for the widget, because by default, it is just as wide as its scroll panel.

Comment: Yes the width when initialized is just fine, I can see the whole cell table. The problem occurs when I try to drag a cell item out of the scroll panel. As I am dragging, it thinks that the panel is getting wider so it autoscrolls horizontally into white space, never letting me drag the item out of the panel